# Centering text overlays over images in div containers

Tags: html, css

I have two images to be displayed in two div boxes. I would like the box positions to be fixed and also for text overlays (captions) on the images. The images keep changing and are of varying sizes, so fixing the size of the box prevents the page elements from jumping around.

Not being an expert on the subject I followed a few tutorials to achieve that, the main ones being [here](http://css-tricks.com/3118-text-blocks-over-image) and [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html).

The code am playing with can be found with and modified [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfkamath/3Gb6e/) and is also pasted below.

Am looking for the caption background to be the exact same width as the caption. And not spill over the side of the image when the image is really small (possibly wrap in that case).

HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">  
<div class="container">
    <div class="wraptocenter">
        <span class="wrimg">
            <div class="shrinkwrapImage">
                <h3 class="caption">Image Caption 1</h3>
                <img src="http://www.google.fr/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />
            </div>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="wraptocenter">
        <span class="wrimg">
            <div class="shrinkwrapImage">
                <h3 class="caption">Image Caption 2</h3>
                <img src="http://www.google.fr/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" width="30%"/>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .container * {
        border:1px solid;
    }
    .container {
        position:relative;
        height:400px;
        width:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .caption {
        position:absolute;
        padding:0.05em;
        top:0.1em; left:120px; right:120px;
        color: white;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        font: 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .wraptocenter .wrimg{
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .wraptocenter * {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .wraptocenter {
        display: block;
    }
    .wraptocenter span {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 1px;
    }
    .wraptocenter .wrimg img{
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.5em #000000;
        border-radius:0.5em;

        max-width:400px;
        max-height:400px;
    }
    .shrinkwrapImage {
        position : relative;
    }
```

Comment: With all the variables here I think your best bet is to use javascript.

Comment: Does the caption need to be centered over the image, *or* do you want the caption positioned at an area in the container (top, bottom, middle), regardless of the height of the image?

Comment: @vonkly over the image relative (pixels) to the top or bottom of the image

Comment: One more question - does the image need to be vertically and horizontally centered in its container? Is there a fixed width/height for the container? I noticed you had it set like this in your example; just wanted to double check.

Comment: @vonkly yes the images need to be vertically and horizontally centered but that works - and the container heights are fixed. The issue is with the centering of captions and restricting the transparent caption background to the width of the text. (I have, since posting this, managed to restrict the background to the width of the image)

Answer (score 2):

The solution that comes to my mind is using a background image

HTML

```
<div id="pictures">
    <div id="picture1">
        <h3 class="caption">Image Caption 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#picture1 { background: url(http://www.google.fr/images/logos/ps_logo2.png) top center no-repeat; width: 400px; height: 500px; }
```

Comment: not sure if I want to use a background image, again am not a css expert so might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the keyword "expression" in CSS, which basically eval JS in your CSS, only works in IE < 8.

I think that I got what you expect here http://jsfiddle.net/sanbor/3Gb6e/8/

Comment: The images are not fixed sizes. So don't want to define fixed widths in either the image or the container margins. (didn't need the expression so updated the question and removed them)

Comment: Does the size of the images are set in percentages?

Comment: the percentage image size was just me playing with image sizes to ensure that the text overlay appears over the image - by shrink wrapping a div around the image (vertically)

Answer (score 0):

**Here's your solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/D9hB3/

The container (yellow background) is a fixed size, as requested. The caption currently sits at the top of the image; simply adjust the `top: 0;` property in the css for `.captioned span` (*note: about 46% will get you a vertically centered caption*). The image can be whatever size you want; the caption will always be at the area you specify (and with the proper width).

**CSS**

```
.container{
    display: table;
    background: yellow;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
.centeritall {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.centeritall .imageWrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.imageWrap span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centeritall">
        <div class="imageWrap">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x200" />
            <span>This is a caption for the image...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```